# git error while push. Suggest possible solutions

Tags: git, github

After pushing the local repository to github, i am getting this error on github.

Compare & pull request
master had recent pushes 2 minutes ago

Images for reference::
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb3jH.jpg

Comment: Why do you think this is an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Background

You're being notified that the `master` branch has been updated because your default branch in GitHub is set to `main`; I can tell this from your screenshot.

This isn't an error reported by GitHub; you're being prompted to raise a *Pull Request* to merge the changes from `master` into `main`.

GitHub now sets `main` to be the default branch. What's likely happened is that your local `git` installation has `master` set to the default or you've created the `master` branch by some other means, such as a script.

```
$ git branch
```

Will list all of the branches you have locally.

---

### My recommendation of what to do:

Click on that "Compare & pull request" button to [create a pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request). Review your changes and then merge into `main`.

After this is done:

1. First ensure you have no local changes by running `git status`. If you do you may want to go through the same *Pull Request* process until you have committed everything.
2. 

```
$ git checkout main
$ git pull
```

At this point you will now have the most up-to-date version of the `main` branch and from here on you can work on this `branch`. Pushing to `main` won't show the same green "Compare & pull request" button as it does when pushing to `master`.

Comment: Sir i appreciate your help.  But this is not very easy for newbee . can you explain it step by step.

Comment: No worries. I'm sure we can step through the problem. Have you read through [this link](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request) from my answer? It expains Pull Requests better than I can :)

Comment: It is little bit complicating because with the big big terms they used in this article. I am giving it one more shot. Lets see what happens

Comment: Click on that "Compare & pull request" button from your screenshot, then click "Create a merge commit" at the bottom of the Pull Request once it is created. Then locally check out the `main` branch: `git checkout main` and then finally run `git pull`. If you aren't using the command line (`git` commands) then let me know what other tool you are using.

Comment: Solved . Thanks sir :)

Comment: Great! Glad to here :) If it was my solution in particular that solved the problem for you, could you [mark the Answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)?